# Magnolia CMS with Spring MVC maven project publish

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, magnolia

When I want to publish my newly created Page in author mode, I got the following error in a popup:

> error detected: Not able to send the activation request [http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia/activation]: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode.

I runned the project with `mvn jetty:run-war`. The maven projects are based of the "Getting started with Blossom" magnolia tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be because you have just single instance? Go to Configuration App, there in the tree to `/server/activation/subscribers/<your subscriber>`. Under subscriber, check the url it points to. Most likely it is invalid. If yes, you can just switch off the subscriber by setting its `enabled` value to `false`. That way you disable publishing completely.

Comment: Thanks @Jan. I switched the /server/activation/subscribers/magnoliaPublic8080/active to false. The publish activity is not throwing error, It is showing the green point in the Status column (Page part). But which is the url where I can reach the Magnolia public instance ? When I try to call: http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/.magnolia It is showing: "Oops, the page you have requested is not available.
Either its URL is incorrect or the page is not available on this channel, i.e. you are looking at it on a desktop browser, but the page is only served on the smartphone channel."

Comment: If you download default tomcat bundle you will see it contains 2 webapps - one will be author and one public. If you instead created your own war file, and deployed it (under e.g. jetty), you will have as many webapps as you deploy. You should always configure one as author and others as public. See more in documentation about how to configure war to bootstrap as author or public: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Instances